# Request error in django view when setting up user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have an app which lets the currently logged in user to create a Person object. That person object has the current logged in user as it's owner.
But as I save the form it give me the following error

```
global name 'request' is not defined
```

I am trying to achieve this using **Django CreateView**

the error trackback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BITSWI~1\Desktop\Maala\Maala\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\Maala\MaalaWeddings\userfiles\views.py" in form_valid
  120.         obj.user_relation = request.user

Exception Type: NameError at /Personadd/
Exception Value: global name 'request' is not defined
```

**Views.py**

```py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.shortcuts import *
    from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
    from .forms import *
    from django.shortcuts import *
    from .models import *
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import *
    from django.http import *
    from datetime import *
    from django.contrib.auth import *
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, DetailView
    from django.views import generic
    from .models import *
    import requests


        class PersonCreate(CreateView):
            model = PersonData
            template_name = "userfiles/add-person.html"

            fields = [
                'person_first_name',
                'person_last_name',
                'person_address',
                'person_email',
                'person_contact_number',
                'person_members'             ]



            def form_valid(self, form):
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.user_relation = request.user
                obj.save()
                return HttpResponse("DONE")
```

**models.py**

```py
class PersonData(models.Model):

    user_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    person_first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=25)

    person_last_name = models.CharField("last Name", max_length=25)

    person_address = models.CharField("Address", max_length=512)

    person_email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=512)

    person_contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField("Phone Number", blank=True, null=True)

    person_members = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        "Family members", blank=True, null=True)
```

I am unable to understand as to why is this error even occurring in the first place, as I thought that *request* is used everywhere in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as you are using a `Class Based View`

all the parameters or variable you want to use needs self to be attached to it

so ,

```
obj.user_relation = self.request.user
```

`self` represents the `instance of the class`. By using the **“self”** keyword we can access the **attributes** and **methods** of the **class**. It binds the **attributes** with the **given arguments**.

Comment: So, it's working :)
Thanks a lot.
I'll accept as soon as the time limit ends

Comment: Can you please briefly tell me what is self actually doing?